# django channels works locally but fails on server

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, django-channels

## Django channels fails to connect in production

i'm working on [a chat application](http://tolk-project.herokuapp.com/) using `django Channels` and reconnecting-web-socket the app works fine locally but when deployed to `heroku` the site works fine but the web socket closes before connection is established and sometimes it works fine.

it tries to connect and says websocket open and established

```
2020-11-21T11:45:14.483101+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.38.231.42:12792 - - [21/Nov/2020:11:45:14] "WSCONNECTING /ws/chat/" - -
2020-11-21T11:45:14.483267+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-11-21 11:45:14,483 DEBUG    Upgraded connection ['10.38.231.42', 12792] to WebSocket
2020-11-21T11:45:14.486434+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-11-21 11:45:14.486 UTC [24] LOG C-0x5564d6f000a0: db1/kutxkggzwbkjsp@127.0.0.1:35034 login attempt: db=db1 user=kutxkggzwbkjsp tls=no
2020-11-21T11:45:14.493134+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-11-21 11:45:14,492 DEBUG    WebSocket ['10.38.231.42', 12792] open and established
2020-11-21T11:45:14.493228+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.38.231.42:12792 - - [21/Nov/2020:11:45:14] "WSCONNECT /ws/chat/" - -
2020-11-21T11:45:14.493405+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-11-21 11:45:14,493 DEBUG    WebSocket ['10.38.231.42', 12792] accepted by application
```

then it tries to connect to the redis db

```
2020-11-21T11:45:14.494880+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-11-21 11:45:14,494 DEBUG    Parsed Redis URI ('redis-10596.c8.us-east-1-2.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com', 10596)
2020-11-21T11:45:14.495020+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-11-21 11:45:14,494 DEBUG    Creating tcp connection to ('redis-10596.c8.us-east-1-2.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com', 10596)
```

but right after that the socket closes

```
2020-11-21T11:45:17.133433+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/ws/chat/" host=tolk-project.herokuapp.com request_id=41ed7690-5f91-4238-9792-01f52c5f65a1 fwd="102.143.218.204" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2654ms status=101 bytes=145 protocol=http
2020-11-21T11:45:17.134597+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-11-21 11:45:17,134 DEBUG    WebSocket closed for ['10.38.231.42', 12792]
2020-11-21T11:45:17.135119+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.38.231.42:12792 - - [21/Nov/2020:11:45:17] "WSDISCONNECT /ws/chat/" - -
2020-11-21T11:45:17.419219+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-11-21 11:45:17,419 DEBUG    Cancelling waiter (<Future cancelled>, [None, None])
2020-11-21T11:45:17.419377+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-11-21 11:45:17,419 DEBUG    Waiter future is already done <Future cancelled>
```

what is causing the connection to close immediately ?

my requirements.txt file:

```
dj-config-url
django==2.2.7
pillow==5.2.0
twisted==19.7.0
asgiref==3.2.2
channels==2.2.0
channels-redis==2.4.0
daphne==2.3.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-redis==4.10.0
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
django-storages==1.9.1
djangorestframework==3.10.3
dropbox==9.4.0
psycopg2==2.8.5
setuptools==40.8.0
whitenoise==4.1.2
twisted==19.7.0
```

my asgi.py file:

```
import os

import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Tolk.settings")
os.environ['ASGI_THREADS'] = "19"
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

my procfile:

```
web: bin/start-pgbouncer-stunnel daphne Tolk.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
```

my settings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for Tolk project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os

import dj_database_url
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

# hosts allowed for use with this application
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'http://tolk-project.herokuapp.com/',
]

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # built-in
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # third party
    'channels',
    'rest_framework',

    # local
    'chat.apps.ChatConfig',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'Authentication.apps.AuthenticationConfig',
    'web_interface.apps.WebInterfaceConfig',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Tolk.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Tolk.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(ssl_require=False)}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files settings
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Authentication Settings
# authentication user model
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing.html
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

#  *****Channels settings******
# root application
ASGI_APPLICATION = "Tolk.routing.application"
# channel layers backends
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [
                f"redis://:{os.environ.get('REDIS_PASSWORD_1')}@{os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST_1')}",
            ],
        },
    },
}


# Redis Cache
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": f"redis://{os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST_2')}",
        'TIMEOUT': 60 * 60 * 24,
        "OPTIONS": {
            'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('REDIS_PASSWORD_2'),
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        },
        "KEY_PREFIX": "chat"
    },
}



# rest framework
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.AdminRenderer',
    ]
}

# **** heroku settings ****
# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals())
# delete ssl mode
del DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS']['sslmode']

# **** dropbox settings ****
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.dropbox.DropBoxStorage'
DROPBOX_OAUTH2_TOKEN = os.environ.get('DROPBOX_OAUTH2_TOKEN')
```

my connect function in consumers.py

```
# used to receive, send messages and keep
# track of online and offline users
class ChatConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    connected_user = None

    async def connect(self) -> None:
        """
        check id user is authenticated if user is
        authenticated the connect to channel and sets up
        a cache db
        """

        if self.scope['user'].is_authenticated:
            # accept user
            await self.accept()
            # to keep track of user
            self.connected_user = self.scope['user']

            cache = caches['default']
            cache.set(f"{self.connected_user.email}", "active")  # cache the user status

            # add your self to your own friend list
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                f'{self.connected_user.id}_friends',
                self.channel_name
            )

            # loop the connected user's friends list and
            # add yourself to the each friend's friend list
            for friend in self.connected_user.contact.friends.all():
                group_name = f'{friend.user.id}_friends'
                await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                    group_name,
                    self.channel_name
                )

            # create a new dict that contains the conversation the user joins
            # every time they connected
            joined_conversations = dict()
            cache.set(f"{self.connected_user.email}_conversations", joined_conversations)
            # close cache
            cache.close()
            # send all notifications that the user has
            await self.send_notifications()
        else:
            await self.close()  # reject connection
```

Note: i also tested this across different browsers

Comment: You should not publish your SECRET_KEY in settings.py in Public. You should keep it safe for security reasons.

Comment: oops i meant to use os.environ.get() but instead wrapped it in quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in reconnecting-web-socket.min.js changing

```
let socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(ws_path)
```

to

```
let socket =  new WebSocket(ws_path)
```

fixed the problem.